# How to change the lib version of an already compiled binary

Tags: c, object, shared

these doubts started coming to me when I read shared library..

1.-------------------------------------------
Suppose I already compiled like below,

```
test  : main.o libtest.so.2
  gcc main.o -L ../../lib -ltest -o test
libtest.so.2  : version2.c
  gcc -Wall -fPIC -c version2.c
  gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so.2.0 version2.o
  ln -sf libtest.so.2.0 libtest.so
  mv libtest.s* ../../lib
main.o  : main.c
  gcc -c main.c
```

having given -ltest, the library should always be a soft link to libtest.so. Correct ?
So what if I go for a higher version of libtest for another binary and the former needs the old version of it ? How do I handle this.

2.-------------------------------------------------------------------------
I have a few libs and I do not wish to include them in LD_LIBRRAY_PATH since everyone will have to search this folder which will be totally relevant to them.

Answer (score 0):

1.You must set version with -soname:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.2 -o libtest.so.2.0 version2.o
```

Then linker will bind former with with "libtest.so.2", not the "any version" of libtest.so.

---

2.Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH only when starting your app, you may create shell script:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/libs ./my_app
```

Comment: Answer to 2 is clear to me. tx

For 1. my question is that if I compiled in the way I showed before, since I did not expect an upgrade, and later I go for an update. I agree to your answer, if I recompile the main, I can do it like below, correct ?


gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.2 -o libtest.so.2.0 version2.o

Comment: Symlink "libtest.so" -> "libtest.so.2.0" is for development use only. When your app is linked against "libtest.so" linker will writer dependency readed from soname of "libtest.so.2.0". It will be "libtest.so.2". When you starting your app loader will search what lib you need, and will find "libtest.so.2"(symlink or real lib) that also can points to any of "libtest.so.2.X" (that is binary-compatible). When you create  "libtest.so.3.0", former will be still linked against "libtest.so.2".